# How to mask or clip rasters in R?

Tags: r

I am working with a marine species that has a shallow distribution, and I would like to delimit modelling of several ascii layers (e.g.SST, SSS) to a 50m depth threshold along the coastline using a bathymetric dataset (e.g. Bio-Oracle, MARSPEC or GEBCO). I am working in R. I do not want bathymetry to be part of the model though. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the bathymetric raster (with values down to 100m depth):

```
class       : RasterLayer 

dimensions  : 600, 420, 252000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)

resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)

extent      : -20, 15, 10, 60  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

data source : in memory

names       : bathy 

values      : -100, -1  (min, max)
```

AND THIS IS RASTER STACK

```
class       : RasterStack 

dimensions  : 600, 420, 252000, 4  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)

resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)

extent      : -20, 15, 10, 60  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 

names       : SST.min, SST.max, SST.range, BO_dissox 

min values  :  -0.120,  10.940,     0.000,     4.052 

max values  :  26.640,  30.320,    21.460,     8.058
```

Cheers,
Rita

Comment: Can you share what type of data the raster contains? Or check out R-package `raster`, it has masking functions

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and provide the details there. What I understand is that you want to remove bathymetry from the raster?

Comment: No, what I want is to remove areas below 100 meters, from all the rasters.

Comment: It's difficult to tell you without seeing the raster itself. Read the documentation on `raster` package. You should be able to obtain or plot the required data. Is the raster available online?

Comment: Or refer this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242941/extracting-values-from-raster-to-get-elevation-values-in-r?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

```
library(raster)
library(marmap)
library(rgdal)

# your coordinate reference setup 
this_crs <- crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
this_extent <- extent(-20, 15, 10, 60)

# a simple raster stack for example purpose
r <- raster(ncol=420, nrow=600, ext = this_extent, crs = this_crs)
values(r) <- (1:ncell(r))/100
r_SST <- sin(r)
r_SSS <- r + runif(ncell(r), 0, 100)^2
r_stack <- stack(r_SST, r_SSS)


# Get some sample bathymetric data to match your stack
# the marmaps package is handy but you could use your own
download_bathy <- getNOAA.bathy(-20, 15, 10, 60, res = 5, keep = TRUE)
bath_mask <- marmap::as.raster(download_bathy)
bath_mask <- projectRaster(from = bath_mask, to = r_stack)

# clip your raster stack to the desired bathymetric limits
bath_mask[bath_mask > 0 | bath_mask < -50] <- NA
clipped_stack <- mask(r_stack, bath_mask)

# check the result with a plot
plot(clipped_stack)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First use SDMPlay:::delim.area in which the first layer of the stack is used to delimit the 100m depth.
Then isolate the bathymetry layer with subset.
User raster:::mask to delimit all rasters to bathymetric area.
And finally remove bathymetry from stack, raster:::dropLayer.

Thanks to all and specially to Guillaumot Charlene!
Rita